# Create directory name based on other other directories

Tags: shell, mv, mkdir

I have directories:

- Foo
- Fee

but I also have some directories with names like:

- Ipsum - Lorem
- Dolor - Sit

If the directory does not contain a hyphen is should be ignored
If the directory does contain a hyphen: Mkdir Ipsum; mv Ipsum\ -\ * Ipsum

Is this possible?

Edit for clarification: If there is a directory with a hyphen I want to create a new directory name based on the part pre-hyphen and then move ALL directories that include the pre-hyphen part into that new directory.

Answer (score 2):

you can use bash substring  expansion feature.

> ${parameter%%word}
>                Remove matching suffix pattern.

```
for f in *;do
    mv "$f" "${f%% -*}"
done
```

Comment: Your response came before my clarification but gave me the missing puzzle pieces I needed to fix my problem. `for f in *;do
    mkdir "${f%% -*}"
    mv "${f%% -*}"\ -* "${f%% -*}";
done  `

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Put code like this in a file, say fix-dashes.sh (I am on Mac OS, but this should work on other Unices):

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
trap 'IFS=$SAVEIFS' 0
for i in $@
do
  echo Processing $i
  case $i in
    *-*)
      echo "'$i' has a dash"
      destname=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/ -.*//')
      echo mv "$i" $destname
      mv "$i" $destname
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Then `bash fix-dash.sh */` will rename the directories as you specified. The slash is important so that you only get directory names, otherwise regular files with dashes will be affected.

`IFS contains the delimiters for the words and since your file names have spaces you need to adjust.

I like using the limited Regular expression mechanism of `case` because it mimics the REs used by `bash` on the command line.  In this case, only names containing dashes will cause the rename to be executed.

The `sed` command does the transformation, in this case, substituting everything after the first  with the null string.